# How to Iterate through a GlobalKTable or KTable in Kafka Streaming App

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streaming App that with 2 data sources: Events and Users.

I have a 4 topics: Events, Users, Users2, User-Events

Users2 is the same as Users and is used to demonstrate the GlobalKTable.

The Events topic uses timestamp mode, so when the timestamp-field date is reached, the KStream will receive the Event record.

At this point, I want to create a User-Event record for every User-ID in the Users KTable along with the new Event-ID; but I don't know how to iterate through the GlobalKTable nor the KTable to achieve this.

```
public Topology createTopology() {

    final Serde<String> serde = Serdes.String();
    final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    final GlobalKTable<String, String> gktUsers =
            builder.globalTable("Users",
                    Materialized.<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("user-store")
                            .withKeySerde(Serdes.String()).withValueSerde(serde));

    final KTable<String, String> ktUsers = builder.table("Users2");

    builder.stream("Events", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), serde))
            .peek((k, v) -> {
                // This is called when a new Event record becomes current.
                // How do I iterate through gktUsers at this point
                // and output a User-ID and an Event-ID to the User-Events topic?

                //  This type of iteration doesn't work either.
                ktUsers.toStream().foreach(new ForeachAction<String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void apply(String s, String s2) {
                        log.info("{} {}", s, s2);
                    }
                });
            })
            
    builder.build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get that statestore to iterate it

```
ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, String> keyValueStore = streams.store("user-store", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore()));

String value = store.get("key");

KeyValueIterator<String, String> range = keyValueStore.all();
```

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html

Or, maybe you should rather be doing a [stream-table join between users and events](https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/kafka-streams/joins/)

Comment: how do I access the "streams" (KafkaStreams) instance from within the Topology?

Comment: The reason I'm not doing a join from Events to Users is because I have no common key in Users that relates to an event. I experimented with adding a fake key of 0 to all the user records, this way I could left join from from Events to Users (global). Unfortunately, my attempts to create working connectors in Kafka have been extremely flakey to the point where I can't create any working Connector today. Very frustrating.

Comment: As shown in the docs, you need to start the topology before you can access the store via the `KafkaStreams` instance. So, seems to me you need two separate topologies. One that builds the table/store, then another than can query said store at runtime, after the other topology is running. But still, you will need a key, if not querying for all the data... Not really clear on your use-case here, but if users are creating events, then your producer should actually put the userId with each event record so you can do some join if you want to expand that ID into a full "event with user details"